# What to unit test in a Builder pattern class

Tags: android, unit-testing

In my Android project, I have a RequestParams object that is built using a Builder pattern.

I was thinking about unit testing that the params set in the Builder are retrieved via the built object.

Besides that, is there anything interesting to unit test in such an object?